# using SQL to remove text in the middle of a string that contains different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL...have you ever had this problem before? 
The goal is to remove "and it's code is (different numbers)" in column prod_description. Is there an SQL command I could use to achieve this?

Table Product

```
prod_id | prod_description
001     | Hi, this is your box and it's code is 123 Mike
002     | Hi, this is your box and it's code is 456 Mike
003     | Hi, this is your box and it's code is 789 Mike
```

I tried using `replace()` and it will not accept the wildcard symbol `'%'` between words as a parameter inut within `replace()`.

---This does not work---

```
SELECT * FROM product
SET prod_description = replace(prod_description,'Hi, this is your box%Mike','')
WHERE prod_description LIKE '%Hi this is your box%Mike%'
```

I want the result to look like this

```
prod_id | prod_description
001     | Hi, this is your box Mike
002     | Hi, this is your box Mike
003     | Hi, this is your box Mike
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can take advantage of handy regexp function [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to do the hard work for you.

```
SELECT 
    prod_id, 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        prod_description, 
        ' and its code is [0-9]+',
        ''
    ) new_prod_description
FROM product;
```

The regexp matches on string `' and its code is '` followed by a sequence of digits, and replaces every match with the empty string. If the string does not match, then it is left untouched.

If you are looking for an `UPDATE` query, as your question somehow suggests, then:

```
UPDATE product
SET prod_description = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    prod_description, 
    ' and its code is [0-9]+', 
    ''
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cq9EhcpK7kbrdigz9oezFc/0)**:

```
| prod_id | new_prod_description      |
| ------- | ------------------------- |
| 1       | Hi, this is your box Mike |
| 2       | Hi, this is your box Mike |
| 3       | Hi, this is your box Mike |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options. It might come down to how consistent your data is.

```
declare @prod_description varchar(100) = 'Hi, this is your box and its code is 123 Mike';
select  left(@prod_description, 20) + right(@prod_description, 5);
select
    left(@prod_description, charindex(' and its code is', @prod_description) - 1)
    + right(' ' + rtrim(@prod_description), charindex(' ', reverse(' ' + rtrim(@prod_description))));
```